# How to Connect TFT LCD display with NodeMCU?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, nodemcu

I am doing this project wherein I want to display some image on the LCD screen. I am having a problem with the connecting nodemcu with my TFT LCD screen. I cannot find any references. Does a TFT screen go well with a NodeMCU? if yes, please help

I tried taking refrence from this website but i ended up damaging my nodeMCU

http://nobrok.com/connecting-tft-lcd-touch-screen-with-nodemcu-esp8266/

Also attaching images of TFT display and my NodeMCU. 
[image: Here's my TFT screen (ILI9341 non touch screen)]

[image: NodeMCU]

It would be great if you can help. Thanks :)

Comment: please provide a link to the display datasheet ...... from the picture, it looks like the display has SPI interface  ( the four SD_ pins )

Comment: it's of some chinese vendor i looked up on their website:   http://www.mcufriend.com/main.html But can't find datasheet for this specific device. But i think it's a modified version of the ILI9341 as mentioned on their website.

Answer (score 1):

According to its web site, the TFT module does have SPI interface. https://www.jixin.pro/product/717.html
The site is in Chinese though.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of TFT doesn't work well with the NodeMCU (or the ESP8266 in general).

Simply put: that TFT requires a lot of GPIO pins - 10 at an absolute bare minimum, but better if you have more available.  The ESP8266 doesn't have many IO pins - and some of them are very sensitive about what they can be connected to without affecting the boot process.

It is better to choose a TFT screen with an SPI interface, which uses far fewer pins - although is slower to refresh the screen data.

If you are careful with your GPIO selection it *may* be possible to work with that screen. There are no specific requirements for what pins need to be connected to where (as far as hardware functionality goes), so it's up to you to find the right combination that doesn't cripple the boot process (stay away from GPIOs 0, 2 and 15 if you can).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the connections given on this link   https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=500773.0  but could not get it to work. If you find something or do have knowledge about it please share. Thanks again!